EmbeddedResource does not update when ResXFileRef file changes
We have a embedded resource:
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\ResourceFile.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>ResourceFile.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>

That .resx file references a TextFile.txt file. That TextFile.txt file is updated correctly. But the Resources.ResourceFile file is not updated.
This works correctly in .NET Framework.
Here is a full minimal solution to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/janssenr/ResourceTest
It contains:
2 Projects: ConsoleAppFramework48, ConsoleAppNet8
Same implementation: Console.WriteLine shows the content of the file TextFile.txt via the ResourcesFile.resx file.
Steps to reproduce:
Open Solution in devenv
Not a problem:
Build and run the ConsoleAppFramework48 project. Some text is shown. (E.g. Hello Framework48: 1)
Edit ConsoleAppFramework48\Resources\Files\TextFile.txt to some different text. (E.g. Hello Framework48: 2)
Build and run ConsoleAppFramework48 again. The new text (E.g. Hello Framework48: 2) is shown.
This is correct.
Problem:
Build and run the ConsoleAppNet8 project. Some text is shown. (E.g. Hello Net8: 1)
Edit ConsoleAppNet8\Resources\Files\TextFile.txt to some different text. (E.g. Hello Net8: 2)
Build and run ConsoleAppNet8 again. The same old text (E.g. Hello Net8: 1) is still there.
This is wrong.

https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/7509

@HansPassant did see that issue. But it's still open. Since Mar 31, 2022
